# Deleting Folder Contents but not the folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder C:\Epson Scans, I am trying to figure out how to write a script that will delete the contents of the folder but leave the folder intact. I have figured out how to delete the entire folder and I could recreate it. But I wanted to know if anyone knows a way of just deleting the contents inside the folder and not actually deleting the folder. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Inserting working code so I can loop through many computers and do it at once. Will someone please tell me why the code is not working where I have inserted it?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Delete_success=0
set total=0

for /F %%G in (pclist.txt) do ( 
    set /a total+=1


pushd "C:\Epson Scans" || exit /B 1
for /D %%I in ("*") do (
    rd /S /Q "%%~I"
)
del /Q "*"
popd

if !ERRORLEVEL!==0 (
        set /a Delete_success+=1
    ) else (
        echo EpsonDelete copy failed on %%G>>EpsonDelete_FailedPCs.txt
    )

)
echo Delete Success: %Delete_success%/%total% >>EpsonDelete_FileCopy.txt
```

Comment: [del /s](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) ?

Comment: do you need to delete subfolders else a del <foldername> /f /q /s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file. Delete all files and folders in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836566/batch-file-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836566/. See the sample script I posted there (the accepted answer on that question is not correct).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`del` deletes files only, so `del /S /Q "C:\Epson Scans"` deletes all files in the given folder and sub-folders (due to `/S`).

`rmdir` deletes folders, so specifying `rmdir /S /Q "C:\Epson Scans"` also deletes the folder `Epson Scans` itself.

Of course you could execute `mkdir "C:\Epson Scans"` afterwards to newly create the deleted folder again<sup>1</sup>, but this was not asked for. So the correct answer is to use a `for /D` loop over `C:\Epson Scans` and delete each folder it contains, and then use `del /Q` to delete the files:

```
pushd "C:\Epson Scans" || exit /B 1
for /D %%I in ("*") do (
    rd /S /Q "%%~I"
)
del /Q "*"
popd
```

Note that `rd` is the same as `rmdir` -- see also this post: [What is the difference between MD and MKDIR batch command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372438)

<sub>1)  Regard that some folder attributes get lost if you do that, for example the owner. Also the case is lost as Windows treats paths case-insensitively.</sub>

Comment: Can you assist me any further please? You code works perfect but I tried inserting it into mine and its breaking I was wondering if you could take a glance at it its very short

Comment: `@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Delete_success=0
set total=0

for /F %%G in (pclist.txt) do ( 
    set /a total+=1


pushd "C:\Epson Scans" || exit /B 1
for /D %%I in ("*") do (
    rd /S /Q "%%~I"
)
del /Q "*"
popd

if !ERRORLEVEL!==0 (
        set /a Delete_success+=1
    ) else (
        echo EpsonDelete copy failed on %%G>>EpsonDelete_FailedPCs.txt
    )
    
)
echo Delete Success: %Delete_success%/%total% >>EpsonDelete_FileCopy.txt`

Comment: any chance you could tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Code is hardly readable in comments, so I suggest to post a new question and to delete your comments here...

Answer (score 0):

del /S C:\Epson Scans*
(use S to delete all files and folders in selected folder)

Comment: `del` will delete all *files* recursively but will leave empty sub-folders behind...

Answer (score 0):

del C:\Epson Scans*.*
if this is batch file you might want to add /Q in order to avoid a delete confirmation dialog:

```
del C:\Epson Scans\*.* /Q
```

Comment: Quotes needed as the path has a space.

Comment: `del` will delete all *files* recursively but will leave empty sub-folders behind...