# Delete only folders using windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have one folder XYZ. In XYZ I have multiple folders and Files.

D:/XYZ/Myfolder1/a1.csv
D:/XYZ/Myfolder2/
D:/XYZ/Myfolder3/
D:/XYZ/aaa.csv
D:/XYZ/bbb.sql

I want to delete folders and every content of that from XYZ 
Like Myfolder1,Myfolder2,Myfolder3
but not aaa.csv and bbb.sql

How can I write batch for this.

Comment: Related answer: [Deleting Folder Contents but not the folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38769816) (simply remove the `del` command from that solution)...

Comment: not related answer ...Not working in my case ...you have to read question first which is very small

Comment: You need to replace `C:\Epson Scans` with `D:\XYZ` in the linked answer. By the way, use *backslashes* in paths! forward-slashes are not standard in Windows and might cause trouble with some commands!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CD c:\windows
For /f "delims=" %A in ('dir c:\windows /b /ad') Do Echo %A [RD %A /s /q deletes the folder %A]
```

See `For /?`, `dir /?,` `rd /?`, and `cd /?`.

Comment: For a batch file it should be double `%`, or am I wrong?

Comment: This is just a small program to echo the command that you would use to delete the folder. However this answer would not keep aaa.csv and bbb.sql...

Comment: Cause it would keep those files. It only deletes directory trees of each folder in the specified folder. It ignores files in the specified folder.

Comment: Thanks guys. Got my answer.